# automatically apply clear formating when pasting text on editor

Tags: wp-editor, text

I know there is a button on the editor that clears the formating styles from other text editors.

But is it possible to apply this clear formating automatically when text is pasted?

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an answer to this question on the tiny mce forum: https://community.tinymce.com/

Comment: As an aside, if you hold shift down while pasting it will do that automatically, also works in Word, Google Docs, etc